# Event propagation does not happen like standard html

Tags: reactjs

I know that react uses its own synthetic implementation of events. However it appears to me that they are not exactly like standard html and this is a problem. In my case I have a checkbox that is a sibling of some img tags. There are two img tags, one for representing checked and another unchecked. I have some css styling that does a display none when the checkbox is in an unchecked state. Trying to get this html/css working with react is hard. It appears that the click event is not propagating onto the checkbox sibling with a react component, although it works from standard html. Note as there's some confusion I know that the non-react version of this is using css and not events. But I'm trying to implement a react evented version of the same thing, and was expecting normal html event propagation behavior--which I'm not seeing. Also note the checkbox is a sibling of the label. It's also transparent, so the user never actually clicks on the checkbox they click on the img tags.

```
.checkbox-image input[type="checkbox"] + label img.selected {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-image input[type="checkbox"] + label img.unselected {
  display: block;
}

<div class="checkbox-image"><input id="portfolio-standard-dev" type="checkbox" data-name="PortfolioStandardDeviation"><label for="mp-chart3"><img class="unselected" src="/images/img-843599.png"><img class="selected" src="/images/img-1b9f30.png"><span>Portfolio Standard Deviation</span></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has nothing to do with events. An event propagation cannot impact your styles.
You have to handle when the user check/uncheck the checkbox and manually update the class of the image.

Or you can try the following pure CSS:

```
.checkbox-image input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label img {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-image input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: block;
}
```